# Windows Store App increment badge notification by one

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, increment, badge

I'm trying to implement Badge notifications in my Windows Store App. Basically, the notification is pushed from the cloud to the client, then a background task is handling it, making toast notification pop up and change the badge number. However, I didn't manage to increase the badge number in any way. For some strange reason, I couldn't find anything online either.

My question: is it possible to retrieve current badge value? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I could find.

So just used a property so that it could be reset by what ever part of the application needed to clear the badge.

```
    private static int _badgecount;
    public int Badgecount
    {
        get
        {
            return _badgecount;
        }
        set
        {
            _badgecount = value;
        }
    }
```